# Pyqt5 QLabel with image at top and text at bottom

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a PyQt5 - QLabel with both image and text. I would like to have a text at the bottom of the image. Below is a part of the code

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        l4=QLabel()
        l4.setText('delete')  
        l4.setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)
        pixmap = QPixmap("/home/moh/Documents/My_GUI/Icons/Delete.png")
        l4.setPixmap(pixmap) 
        l4.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)         

        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(l4, 0, 0)


        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use 2 QLabel in a QVBoxLayout:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        pixmap_label = QLabel(
            pixmap=QPixmap("/home/moh/Documents/My_GUI/Icons/Delete.png")
        )
        text_label = QLabel(text="delete")

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(pixmap_label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(text_label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a circle Qlabel image, use this code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPainterPath, QPainter
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class Label(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, antialiasing=True, **kwargs):

        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.Antialiasing = antialiasing
        self.setMaximumSize(90, 90)
        self.setMinimumSize(90, 90)
        self.radius = 45 

        self.target = QPixmap(self.size())  
        self.target.fill(Qt.transparent)   

        p = QPixmap("Image.jpg").scaled(  
        90, 90, Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding, Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        painter = QPainter(self.target)
        if self.Antialiasing:
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
            painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(
        0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)

        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(self.target)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        pixmap_label = Label()
        text_label = QLabel(text="delete")
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(pixmap_label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        lay.addWidget(text_label, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. Also, make sure that you are NOT making any assumptions while answering questions. You can comment when you reach 50 reputation to ask for clarification.